# results from find_by_email executed in function differs from console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to Rails and i'm currently learning from tutorials from http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-and-viewing-users-one#top

find_by_email works on console, however, when I execute find_by_email on User.authenticate("test@test.com","testing")
I get a nil returned

Where have I possibly gone wrong ?

Below is part of the codes from my model, User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor   :password
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :name,     :presence      => true, 
                       :length        => { :maximum => 50 }
  validates :email,    :presence      => true,
                       :format        => { :with => email_regex },
                       :uniqueness    => { :case_sensitive => false }

  validates :password, :presence      => true,
                       :confirmation  => true,
                       :length        => { :within => 6..40 }

  before_save :encrypt_password

  # Return true if the user's password matches the submitted password.
  def has_password?(submitted_password)
    # Compare encrypted_password with the encrypted version of
    # submitted_password.
    encrypted_password == encrypt(submitted_password)
  end

  def self.authenticate(email, submitted_password) 
    user = find_by_email(email)
    return nil if user.nil?
    # return nil if user.has_password?(submitted_password)
  end
```

I have tried User.find_by_email("test@test.com") on rails console, and I was returned with the record on my local database.

Comment: Have you actually tried `User.find_by_email` in the console or are you just perplexed that your IRB isn't auto-completing it?  Please try it in your console and put the output in an edit in your question.

Comment: Did you run the migration for the above model?

Comment: yes I did.  I'm able to do a signup with encrypted passwords. but for some reason, find_by_email doesn't work.. I'm sure I must have messed up somewhere.. but I'm not too sure where.. I do know that I need to declare an attribute email on my model. right?

Comment: Are you using irb or rails console?  Please do as Brett suggested, output please!

Comment: I sincerely apologize. It was a typing error on console. find_by_email is working now on console. However, when I try to run find_by_email in my method, it returns nil.

Comment: I sincerely apologize. It was a typing error on console. find_by_email is working now on console. However, when I try to run find_by_email in my method, it returns nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a problem with your authenticate method.  Ruby always returns the value of the last line it executes in a method.  Since the last line in your method is:

```
return nil if user.nil?
```

This is the same as:

```
if user.nil?
  return user
end
```

When your user is correct, the code inside the if does not get executed, but there is still no return value afterwards, so authenticate returns nil regardless.  I would try this instead of your `return nil if user.nil?` line:

```
return user if user
```

or if you prefer explicitness:

```
return user unless user.nil?
```

or even more explicit:

```
return user.nil? ? nil : user
```

As long as you explicitly return the user as the last line, I think everything should be fine.

Comment: You're welcome, good luck making it through those chapters :)