# Rails Tutorial 3.2 Chapter 8 error: NoMethodError in SessionsController#create

Tags: railstutorial.org, nomethoderror

I'm going through the rails tutorial and my login page is throwing an exception after exercise 8.1.5 when I click the login button with no email or pw entered:
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec-rendering_with_a_flash_message

Error:

```
NoMethodError in SessionsController#create
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:7:in `create'
```

SessionsController matches the final code exactly for the Create method

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase) #line 7
    if user && User.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      #will fill this in later
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end
end
```

I did change the button label to Log in instead of "Sign in" as that is too confusing with "Sign up", but I didn't think that would create the problem.  sessions\new.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "Log in") %>
<h1>Log in</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(:sesssion, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.text_field :email %>

        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password %>

        <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>

    <% end %>
    <p>New user? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path %></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This post hints that I need a method in my user model, but adding that didn't help:
[NoMethodError in SessionsController#create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969569/nomethoderror-in-sessionscontrollercreate)

I tried adding this to user.rb, but it didn't help
[results from find_by_email executed in function differs from console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019712/results-from-find-by-email-executed-in-function-differs-from-console):

```
def self.authenticate(email, submitted_password) 
    user = find_by_email(email)
    return user.nil? ? nil : user
end
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, do you have the User.authenticate(params[:session][:password]) method? In your User.rb file.

Comment: No - I tried adding this, but it didn't help:      def self.authenticate(email, submitted_password) 
     user = find_by_email(email)
  return user.nil? ? nil : user
 end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked at the example from  the book and your code and I noticed this line

```
if user && User.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
```

your User.authenticate should be lowercased to user.authenticate. Revert back to your original code.

Comment: Thanks - no luck adding that to user.rb :(  I tried changing your above to use email instead of name too, and still no luck.  My request shows the session param with email & pw included, but if i have params[:session][:email], I always get the error.  For example - this creates an error on the same line: @email=params[:session][:email]

Comment: Hold on let me take a look at the example and get back to you.

Comment: I've corrected the answer. You should remove the method I mentioned in the first response. Hopefully it works now!

Comment: I really appreciate your time - lowercase "u" didn't work for me with any combo (User in users.rb auth method, user in sessions_controller, user, Users, nor user, user)

Comment: btw-also commented out the new user.authenticate method in users.rb and tried upper & lowercase.  It seems to error on the param assignment line vs the authenticate method, but the stack trace shows the params should be there and should be fine.

Comment: Can you try this  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase) 
    if user 
      #will fill this in later
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

Comment: Summary of the below - sessions_controller.rb & users.rb are both fine, I broke something in routes.rb, or header.html.erb, or new.html.erb.  I ended up bailing on my routes.rb, header.html.erb, and new.html.erb for sessions customizations to use "Log in" and "login" instead of "Sign in" and "signin", which got me past the problem.  I'm still determined to figure out the exact change that broke the above, and will update this thread once resolved.  Thanks again for all the time!

Comment: Yes please do! I'm not sure if you know this but in your console, you could type "rake routes" to get all the available routes and to which functions they point to and what params you could get into them. You're welcome. Just wish I could've helped better.

Comment: You were right - lowercase u did the trick, but still not sure why it took me replacing my other files to get it to work.  I went through and checked all my other files and recreated my customizations.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: That's really great. Sometimes unlike PHP, rails doesn't take change immediately even though it should. Sometimes restarting the server does wonders! You're welcome again :)

Answer (score 0):

I have just had the same problem and found that in fact i needed [:sessions] with an s on the end!

So line reads

```
if user && User.authenticate(params[:sessions][:password])
```

Hope this helps someone in the future!

Comment: I'm searching for a solution as well... When I add the s, I get a "invalid hash" error.

Comment: When I'm using "session" and the login info is correct, it works! BUT when the login info is wrong I get the invalid hash error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after doing exercise 1 in chapter 8 where I replaced the use of `form_for` with `form_tag`. This resulted in the name attributes in the generated input form fields changing from `name="session[email]"` and `name="session[password]"` to `name="email"` and `name="password"`. Subsequently, I needed to access the params using `params[:email]` and `params[:password]` instead of `params[:session][:email]` and `params[:session][:password]`.

My new Sessions controller looks like this:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

This solved the problem for me. Hope this is helpful to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

In this section from the tutorial chapter 8, all instances of [:session] should be [:sessions]. Hope that helps.

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  .
  .
  .
  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end
  .
  .
  .
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you confirm the word 'session' in app/view/session/new.html.erb spelling correct?

I see you wrote:

> form_for(:**sesssion**, url: sessions_path) do |f|

But in app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb, you wrote:

> user = User.find_by_email(params[:**session**][:email].downcase) #line 7

They must be the same.